# Problema con mutate(na.rm)

Tags: r, r-dplyr

He llegado por fin a una función para plotear mis *outliers* por una variable *id*, pero me falla estrepitosamente al encontrar un *missing Value*.

He intentado variar la función *is_outlier* para que acepte *Na's* pero el problema fundamental es el del *mutate*, el cual no consigo ponerle el argumento que me está dando como fallo.

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `is_outlier`. x missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE i Input `is_outlier` is `ifelse(is_outlier(disp), disp, as.numeric(NA))`. i The error occurred in group 3: cyl = 8. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Aquí dejo el código con mtcars como ejemplo.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

library(ggrepel)



is_outlier <- function(x) {
  
  if (is.na(x)==FALSE) {
  return(x < quantile(x, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x)) }
  else{ return(FALSE)}
  
  
}


# mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(var="id") # we put a var "id" 
# # varid -> variable id
# # var1 -> variable to plot
# # varby -> variable to factor boxplot
# # vaird
outlier_idplotter <- function(var1="drat",dat =mtcars2, varby="cyl",varid="id") { ## Had to change the order for the apply

# varid = "id"
# var1 = "mpg"
# varby = "cyl"


dat <- dat %>% group_by(!!sym(varby)) %>% mutate(var = (!!sym(var1)), funs(is_outlier= ifelse(is.na(!!sym(var1)),as.numeric(NA),
                                                                    ifelse( is_outlier(!!sym(var1)),!!sym(var1), as.numeric(NA))) ) )
  
  
 



## id = "something". ¿How do i call this?
dat$id[which(is.na(dat$is_outlier))] <- as.numeric(NA)   # Dont want to do this.
# dat[,"id"][which(is.na(dat[,"is_outlier"]))] <- as.numeric(NA) # Cant get this to work.

# varid = "id"
ggplot(dat, aes(y=!!sym(var1), x=factor(!!sym(varby)))) + geom_boxplot() + geom_text_repel(aes(label=!!sym(varid)),na.rm=TRUE,nudge_y=0.05)


# p+geom_text_repel(data=filter(results, padj<0.05), aes(label=Gene))
}
```

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(var="id") # we put a var "id"
(mt_lista = colnames(mtcars2)[c(2,4:6)])
lapply(mt_lista,outlier_idplotter,dat =mtcars2, varby="cyl",varid="id") # Everything good here.

mtcars2_out = mtcars2[15,2]=NA
lapply(mt_lista,outlier_idplotter,dat =mtcars2, varby="cyl",varid="id") ##But now.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es que `is_outlier()` omita los registros `NA` y regrese el output solo para los datos válidos y `NA` cuando una fila es `NA`. En ese caso podrías modificar las llamadas a las funciones que tiene dentro para que se comporten de esa manera. Tanto `IQR()` como `quantile()` aceptan el argumento `na.rm =` , que por defecto es `FALSE` y regresa un error si se encuentra con un `NA`.

En ese caso podrías modificar la función:

```
is_outlier <- function(x) {
    
    x < quantile(x, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE) - 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE) | x > quantile(x, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE) + 1.5 * IQR (x, na.rm = TRUE) }
```

Me parece que este caso `mutate()` es solo el mensajero que comunica el error, pero lo hace porque la función que está aplicando (`is_outlier()`) está pasando un error, que a su lo reporta de la función interna `quantile()`.

¿Resuelve tu problema?

Comment: Sí que lo hace, sí. Lo había "resuelto" filtrando previamente los datos tal que: dat <-dat %>% filter(!is.na(!!sym(var1)))   previo a la definición de data. Gracias por la aclaración última porque no entendía por qué mutate no me admitía el argumento, siendo la culpa de la función is_outlier().